# Stirling's Approximation for a probability distribution

Tags: probability, logarithms, approximation, mathematica

I have a probability distibution:
$$Pr(n_E) =\frac{1}{4^S}\frac{(2 S)!}{(S-n_E)! (S +n_E)!}$$
To simplfy this into something useful, I take the log of the probability and use Stirling's approximation, which is $$\ln\left[x!\right]\to x\ln\left[x\right] - x$$
when x is sufficiently large.
$$\begin{align}
\ln\left[Pr(n_E)\right] &= \ln\left[\frac{1}{4^S}\frac{(2 S)!}{(S-n_E)! (S +n_E)!}\right]\\
&=\ln\left[(2S)!\right] - \ln\left[(S-n_E)!\right] - \ln\left[(S+n_E)!\right] - S\ln\left[4\right]\\\\
&\hspace{1cm}\text{Using Sterling's approximation}\\\\
&=\left(\begin{aligned}
&2S\ln\left[2S\right] -2S - (S-n_E)\ln\left[S-n_E\right] + (S-n_E)\\
&\hspace{0.5cm} - (S+n_E)\ln\left[S+n_E\right] + (S+n_E) - S\ln\left[4\right]
\end{aligned}\right)\\
&=2S\ln\left[2S\right] -  (S-n_E)\ln\left[S-n_E\right] -  (S+n_E)\ln\left[S+n_E\right] - S\ln\left[4\right]
\end{align}$$
However, plotting the probability distribution before and after using Stirling's approximation yields extremely different amplitudes. Why?

[Plot before Stirling's approximation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVlGd.jpg)

[image]

Mathematica Code:

```
DiscretePlot[ Exp[Log[(2 S)!] - Log[(S - nE)!] - Log[(S + nE)!] - S Log[4]] /. {S -> 100}, {nE, -9, 9}]
```

[Plot after Stirling's approximation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Hpm.jpg)

[image]

Mathematica Code:

```
DiscretePlot[Exp[2 S Log[2S] - (S - nE) Log[S - nE] - (S + nE) Log[S + nE] - S Log[4]] /. {S -> 100}, {nE, -9, 9}]
```

**EDIT 1:** Updated Graph 2 to corrected algebra and included higher order Stirling approximation:
**EDIT 2:** Fixed @Henry's plot by changing sign of $\ln\left[\pi\right]$ term.

[More Accurate Stirling Approximation suggested by @Henry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cITGE.jpg)
[image: Higher Order Stirling Approximation suggested by @Henry]

```
DiscretePlot[Exp[(2 S + 1/2) Log[S] - (S - nE + 1/2) Log[S - nE] - (S + nE + 1/2) Log[S + nE] - 1/2 Log[\[Pi]] /. {S -> 100}, {nE, -9, 9}]
```

Comment: Apologies @Henry those graphs were the wrong way around.

Comment: 2S Log[**2S**], which in your code was mistaken as 2S Log[S].

Comment: @CaveJohnson corected but still inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have written a partly cancelled  `Exp[2 S Log[S] - ... - S Log[4]]` rather than an uncancelled version something like `Exp[2 S Log[2 S] - ... - S Log[4]]` or a cancelled version like `Exp[2 S Log[S] - ... ]`.  But even that will be a poor approximation.

You could benefit from a more accurate version of Stirling's approximation such as  $$\ln( x!) \approx x\ln( x) - x + \tfrac12\ln(2\pi x)$$

which I think would make your calculation

$$Pr(n_E) =\frac{1}{4^S}\frac{(2 S)!}{(S-n_E)! (S +n_E)!} \\\approx \exp\left[ 
(2S+\tfrac12)\ln(S)-(S-n_E+\tfrac12)\ln(S-n_E)-(S+n_E+\tfrac12)\ln(S+n_E) -\tfrac12 \ln\left(\pi\right) \right]  $$

Comment: Corrected algebra in question, and replotted. Thanks for pointing that out. Also included more accurate version, however still large discrepencies.

Comment: My mistake - it should have been $-\frac12 \ln(\pi)$ rather than  $+\frac12 \ln(\pi)$

Comment: That certainly corrected the mis-match. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Stirling's Approximation gives
$$
\log(x!)\sim x\log(x)-x+\frac12\log(2\pi x)\color{#CCC}{+\frac1{12x}-\frac1{360x^3}+\frac1{1260x^5}-\dots}\tag1
$$
Applying the main (dark) part of $(1)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac1{4^S}\frac{(2S)!}{(S+n)!(S-n)!}\right)
&\sim-\frac12\log(\pi)+\left(\frac12+2S\right)\log(S)\\
&\phantom{\,\sim\,}-\left(S-n+\frac12\right)\log(S-n)\\
&\phantom{\,\sim\,}-\left(S+n+\frac12\right)\log(S+n)\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Approximating $\log(S+n)=\log(S)+\frac nS-\frac{n^2}{2S^2}$ and $\log(S-n)=\log(S)-\frac nS-\frac{n^2}{2S^2}$ in $(2)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac1{4^S}\frac{(2S)!}{(S+n)!(S-n)!}\right)
&\sim-\frac12\log(\pi S)+\left(\frac1{2S^2}-\frac1S\right)n^2\tag3\\
&\sim-\frac12\log(\pi S)-\frac{n^2}S\tag4
\end{align}
$$
$(4)$ is the asymptotic approximation of $(3)$ where $\frac1{2S^2}-\frac1S$ is replaced by $-\frac1S$.

Therefore,
$$
\frac1{4^S}\frac{(2S)!}{(S+n)!(S-n)!}\sim\frac1{\sqrt{\pi S}}e^{-n^2/S}\tag5
$$
Plotting `DiscretePlot[1/Sqrt[Pi S]Exp[-n^2/S]/.S->100,{n,-9,9}]` gives

[image]

Comment: The gaussian plot of this probability distribution makes alot of intuition!